# DB2 IMPORT from Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, resultset, db2-luw

I  am trying to write a procedure to  verify if there was any issues during import so I can raise an error. So I wrote the following block of SQL inside of my stored procedure. But I always get a null value for all the fetched values(`actualRowCount`, `skippedRowCount`, `importedRowCount`, `updatedRows`, `rejectedRows`, `committedRows`) except for the `msgs`.

I am unable to find why would I get values only for the `msgs` but not for others. They all should have at least `0` as a value. Please Assume all necessary variables declared in the procedure already.

I get a `DB2 SQL-Error: -438` when I do a `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` outside of the If block for testing purpose and get a null error when I try to print using `Put_LINE`

```sql
Begin Atomic
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'IMPORT FROM /tmp/city.ixf  OF ixf MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT INTO city');
ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATORS(resultSet) WITH PROCEDURE SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD;
ALLOCATE C1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET resultSet;
FETCH  C1 INTO actualRowCount, skippedRowCount , importedRowCount, updatedRows, rejectedRows, committedRows, msgs;
IF actualRowCount <> importedRowCount THEN
 CALL RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20040, 'import fail:' || msgs);
END IF;
Close C1;
End;
```

Comment: The result set contains 8 columns, not 7. You should run the dynamic select statement returned in the 7-th parameter and process its result set to understand, what happened with import. Finally, you should run the call statement returned in the 8-th parameter dynamically to cleanup the corresponding messages from the server's file system. See [IMPORT using ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sample message handler for IMPORT with ADMIN_CMD:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE actualRowCount, skippedRowCount, importedRowCount, updatedRows, rejectedRows, committedRows BIGINT;
  DECLARE msg_sel, msg_del VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
  DECLARE V_SQLCODE VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE V_MSG VARCHAR(1024);
  DECLARE resultSet RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;
  DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR S2;

  CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('IMPORT FROM /tmp/city.ixf  OF ixf MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT INTO city');
  ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATORS (resultSet) WITH PROCEDURE SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD;
  ALLOCATE C1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET resultSet;
  FETCH  C1 INTO actualRowCount, skippedRowCount , importedRowCount, updatedRows, rejectedRows, committedRows, msg_sel, msg_del;
  CLOSE C1;
  IF COALESCE(msg_sel, '') <> '' THEN
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('msg_sel: ' || msg_sel);
    PREPARE S2 FROM msg_sel;
    OPEN C2;
    L2: LOOP
      FETCH C2 INTO V_SQLCODE, V_MSG; 
      IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L2; END IF;
      CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQLCODE || ': ' || V_MSG);
    END LOOP L2;
    CLOSE C2;
  END IF;
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('msg_del: ' || msg_del);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE msg_del;
END@
```